# Align dom element to the bottom of another fixed-top element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that is fixed to the top of the screen.  In the div there is a search area where you make ajax calls and fetch data into the div, and that changes the div height.

Also there is another div called "ThingsToAlign".  I want to align this to the bottom of the fixed-top div.

Any one knows how to do this?  I tried `vertical-align` or `float: top` but none of them are working..  Thanks.

```
<div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="navbar-fixed-top">
      <SearchArea />
    </div>
    <div>
      <ThingsToAlign/>
    </div>
</div>
```

In bootstrap the class navbar-fixed-top has the following properties.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

p.s: I was coding in react.js so that's why you see "className" instead of "class"

Comment: why are you using `className` ? Shouldn't it be `class` if you are assigning classes to `div`

Comment: Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvs0cc31/). Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: fiddle is something like this posted by @Michael_B . http://jsfiddle.net/kdbsm3hz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your HTML attribute `className` is incorrect (in standard HTML). It should be `class`.

Second, you should try to stay away from using angle brackets to surround demo text. The browser will consider it a tag and ignore it (i.e., it will be invisible when rendered).

Your question is not entirely clear to me, but from what I understand this demo may be helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/kdbsm3hz/

Otherwise, you may find a solution in other similar questions:

- [How do I use CSS to position a fixed variable height header and a scrollable content box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6414384/3597276)
- [Position DIV below fixed div with variable height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6569681/3597276)
- [Placing a scrollable div below a fixed div of variable height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21706915/3597276)
- [Scrollable div beneath a variable height header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21186179/3597276)
- [Creating a variable height "fixed" header in CSS with scrollable content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6763095/3597276)

Comment: oh I was coding in react actually.

Comment: Take this fiddle for example, I am hoping to get rid of the yellow area.  The problem is the blue area sometimes have heights of 1000px which covers part of the red part.

Comment: You may need to create a duplicate "SearchArea" div with `visibility: hidden`, or use JavaScript, to push down "ThingsToAlign". I've updated my answer with various references.

Comment: thank you. I managed to solved this with javascript using first link.  But I was wondering if there are css ways to solve it?  I am worried javascript will have side effects on react.js rendering components...

Comment: By using fixed positioning on the SearchArea div you are removing it from the normal flow of the document. This means that other elements don't even know it exists, so they won't adjust to its variable height.

Comment: If SearchArea was a fixed height, the problem could be easily solved with CSS. But since it's a variable height, something needs to tell other elements what the height is at every instance. JS can do this. Another solution, which I mentioned before and is described in linked answers, would be an invisible duplicate div. This would be really hackey and require extra mark-up, so is not a preferred alternative.

Comment: Let me know if anything can be changed in your mark-up, and I'll try again to provide a pure CSS solution.

Comment: I see.  ya should keep it simple and go with the straightforward option here. Thank you!