# How can I put a div right next to a fixed-to-the-left div while keeping the fixed div's width auto?

Tags: css

I tried this:

```
<div id="fixed-navigation">...<div>

<div id="content">...<div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#fixed-navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#content {
  background: yellow;
}
```

See: http://codepen.io/zssz/pen/LGEJOJ

But this hides part of the content div below the fixed div, and setting an arbitrary `margin-left` or something on `#content` would just ignore the variable auto width on `#fixed-navigation`.

So what's the right CSS way to accomplish this seemingly simple use case? (I do want the fixed navigation to be fixed, that is it must always stay on the left side while scrolling through the content)

EDIT: Oh sorry, and I forgot to mention it should work in the majority of actual browsers out there including IE9, so alas not flexbox to the rescue.

Comment: Without flexbox you're most likely going to need JS. I recently answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33991757/3597276

Answer (score -1):

Here's a flex box implementation:

http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/OMPBmp

The essential stuff is...

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

`display: flex` on the container, in this case `body`, then...

```
#fixed-navigation {
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great, but alas I need to support the majority of actual browsers out there, So flexbox isn't an option yet, too bad. See my edit.

Comment: Global browser support for flex is currently over 95% and usage of IE 9 is at 0.94% fwiw ;)

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Yeah good point, I do need IE9 though :( C'mon please don't tell me this isn't possible without flexbox :(